# Issue with concealed symbols

Tags: vim, syntax

I have `&concealcursor=nc`  and this works fine except one thing: say, I have a following line: "`foo bar  ~*baz*~ foo`", and the symbols `~` and `*` are concealed. I move cursor through this line, and cursor stuck on concealed symbols.

And this isn't worse thing: say, I want to select word `baz`. I put cursor on this word, start selecting, and now I see that cursor is NOT at letter `b`, but at symbol `~`.

I have to re-select it carefully, to make sure I select what I want. This is really annoying.

I believe Vim should handle this and jump over these consealed symbols, to make it clear. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not going to happen.  Vim's concealing feature is just that, it only conceals things from view.  Any editing or motions will be unaffected by whether or not a specific character is currently concealed.

Comment: Pity. I wrote to vim-dev, Christian Brabandt said: "I think it is somewhere in the todo list together with the other conceal issues. I don't know, if this is actively being worked on."